# Migrating Websphere 7 to 8.5.5

Tags: migration, websphere-8

We have WebSphere Platform 7.0.0.19 and trying to migrate to new WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.11. 
Application server wont start because some strange error:

```
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.jca.J2CCommandHelper.getNewPropertyListFromComparison(J2CCommandHelper.java:384)
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.jca.J2CCommandHelper.getNewPropertyListFromComparison(J2CCommandHelper.java:172)
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.reconcileJ2CObjects(ConfigureTask.java:885)
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask(ConfigureTask.java:390)
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
[14.02.17. 13:53:50:504 CET] 000000a1 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
```

application.xml inside EAR project contains this module that apparently is problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
    <display-name>
    myAppEAR</display-name>
    <module id="EjbModule_1222878922372">
        <ejb>myAppEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module id="EjbModule_1222955615688">
        <ejb>Server.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module id="WebModule_1222955629907">
        <web>
            <web-uri>maAppWebServices.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>myAppWebServices</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <module id="ConnectorModule_1222955641688">
        <connector>VagenConnector.rar</connector>
    </module>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>myApp</role-name>
    </security-role>
</application>
```

When ConnectorModule_1222955641688 is removed it works?

Comment: Is the embedded resource adapter named VagenConnector.rar in your EAR file.  The module element ConnectorModule_1222955641688 refers to it.

Comment: VagenConnector is standalone project and we solved problem by regenerating projects META-INF/ra.xml. This we accomplished via (right click on project) J2EE -> Specifications Upgrade Wizard :). Very lucky guess !

Answer (score 0):

VagenConnector is standalone project and we solved problem by regenerating projects META-INF/ra.xml. This we accomplished via (right click on project)

```
J2EE -> Specifications Upgrade Wizard
```